# Can't enter data into sql database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I am using this code to add some data to my already existing sql database, but the can't seem to do so, it's also not giving any errors. I have tried everything that i could think of. This is a form which lets user input the data and then when user clicks submit it gives a success message in url but i get the success message but no data in my database.

```php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Signup Form</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="signup.php" method="POST">
        <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name">
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name">
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="E-mail">
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="uid" placeholder="User name">
        <br>
        <input type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="Password">
        <br>
        <button type="submit" name="submit">Sign up</button>
        &nbsp;
    </form>

<?php
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM users;" ;
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);          //connects the database to the query we just generated
    $resultcheck = mysqli_num_rows($result);        // it returns the number of rows in the query

    if($resultcheck > 0){
        //the if condition checks if there is any data inside $resultcheck
        //The mysqli_fetch_assoc() function fetches a result row as an associative array.
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
            echo $row['user_uid'].'<br>';
        }
    }
?>

</body>
</html>
```

```php
<?php
    include_once 'dbh.php';

    $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
    $lastname = $_POST['lastname'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $uid = $_POST['uid'];
    $pwd = $_POST['pwd'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (`user_firstname`, `user_firstname`, `user_email`, `user_uid`, `user_pwd` ) VALUES (\'$firstname\',\'$lastname\',\'$email\',\'$uid\', \'$pwd\');";

    //require 'dbh.php';

    mysqli_query('$conn','$sql');

    /* if($result=$mysqli->query($sql)){
    echo "<p>User successfully added to database</p>".'<br>';
    }
    else{
        echo "Error enterting user into database!".mysql_error().'<br>';
    } */

    header("Location: index.php?signup=success");
?>
```

```php
<?php
    $dbServername = "localhost";
    $dbUsername = "root";
    $dbPassword = "";
    $dbName = "login_system";               // selecting the database

    $conn = mysqli_connect($dbServername,$dbUsername,$dbPassword,$dbName );
    //$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','root',"",$dbName );

    if(mysqli_connect_errno()){
        printf("connection failed %s\n",mysqli_connect_error());
        exit();
    }

    $mysqli->select_db("login_system");
?>
```

Comment: Please read about ["SQL Injection"](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php). Your code is vulnerable.

Answer (score 1):

Please remove single quotes in $conn and $sql

```
mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
```

in your insert PHP file.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `users` (`user_firstname`, `user_lastname`, `user_email`, `user_uid`, `user_pwd` ) VALUES ('".$firstname."', '".$lastname ."', '".$email."', '".$uid."', '".$pwd."');";
$result=mysqli_query('$conn','$sql');
if($result)
{
    echo "succsessfuly...";
}
else
{
    echo "Not succsessfuly...";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
<?php
include_once 'dbh.php';
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title> Signup Form </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="signup.php" method="POST">
            <input type="text" name="firstname" placeholder="First Name">
            <br>
            <input type="text" name="lastname" placeholder="Last Name">
            <br>
            <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="E-mail">
            <br>
            <input type="text" name="uid" placeholder="User name">
            <br>
            <input type="password" name="pwd" placeholder="Password">
            <br>
            <button type="submit" name="submit">Sign up</button>
            &nbsp;
        </form>
        <?php
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users; " ;
        $result = $mysqli->query($sql);             //connects the database to the query we just generated
        $resultcheck = $result->num_rows;       // it returns the number of rows in the query

        if($resultcheck > 0){
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                echo $row['user_uid'].'<br>';
            }
        }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

**signup.php**

```
<?php
include_once 'dbh.php';

$firstname = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['firstname']);
$lastname = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['lastname']);
$email = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$uid = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['uid']);
$pwd = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['pwd']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO users (`user_firstname`, `user_lastname`, `user_email`, `user_uid`, `user_pwd` ) VALUES ('$firstname','$lastname','$email','$uid', '$pwd');";


if($result=$mysqli->query($sql)){
    echo "<p>User successfully added to database</p>".'<br>';
}
else{
    echo "Error enterting user into database!".$mysqli->error.'<br>';
}

header("Location: index.php?signup=success");
```

**dbh.php**

```
<?php

$dbServername = "localhost";
$dbUsername = "root";
$dbPassword = "";
$dbName = "login_system";               // selecting the database


$mysqli = new mysqli($dbServername,$dbUsername,$dbPassword,$dbName);

if($mysqli->connect_errno){
    printf("connection failed %s\n",$mysqli->connect_error);
    exit();
}
```

Please read this reference http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Answer (score -1):

should be like this

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO users (firstname, lastname, email, uid, pwd ) VALUES ('$firstname','$lastname','$email','$uid', '$pwd')";

mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
```

Comment: I think that's a bad answer: this invoke doing SQL injection which is always bad.

Comment: Thank you for the answer but the changes you are suggesting are not viable, as the names i have in my database are user_name/mail.

Comment: add if(isset($_POST['submit']))  {  } before $firstname = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['firstname']);

Comment: if(isset($_POST['submit']))  { $firstname = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['firstname']);
$lastname = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['lastname']);
$email = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$uid = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['uid']);
$pwd = $mysqli->real_escape_string($_POST['pwd']);

$sql = "INSERT INTO users (`user_firstname`, `user_lastname`, `user_email`, `user_uid`, `user_pwd` ) VALUES ('$firstname','$lastname','$email','$uid', '$pwd');";


if($result=$mysqli->query($sql)){
    echo "<p>User successfully added to database</p>";
}
 }